# Force screen resolution in Lubuntu

Tags: xrandr, resolution

Connecting an ASRock Beebox N3000 with Lubuntu 16.04 to a Sony Bravia with a HDMI cable this is the output of `xrandr`:

```
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 32767 x 32767
DP1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI1 connected 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 735mm x 420mm
   1920x1080i    50.00*+  60.00    59.94  
   1280x720      60.00    50.00    59.94  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x576i      50.00  
   720x480       60.00    59.94  
   720x480i      60.00    59.94  
   640x480       60.00    59.94  
HDMI2 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI3 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
VIRTUAL1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
```

1920x1080i is supposed to work well, but it results in a too wide desktop, such that it does not stay within the screen limits. Another laptop connected by VGA performs reasonably well with 1360x768, but this resolution is not supported here. `xrandr --addmode HDMI1 1360x768` results in

```
xrandr: cannot find mode "1360x768"
```

don't know if this modeline can be added.

I have also tried to change the TV configuration, but there's little to do under a HDMI connection.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to adjust the scale.
This is what i usually do when i connect my laptop (res 1366 x 768) to a 1920X1080 TV (mirror mode) using VGA cable.
This command worked fine for me , and resolution of TV was pretty good:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --mode 1366x768 --scale 1x1 --output VGA-1 --same-as LVDS-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 0.711x0.711
```

PS: You might need to experiment a little bit with scale factor

If you want to turn off your laptop screen you could try:

```
xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off --output VGA-1 --mode 1920x1080 --scale 0.711x0.711
```

PS2: You might need to change LVDS-1 to your internal laptop monitor name.

**Update:**

If you want to add a new mode and do not apply the --scale workaround then see this example and also see [this post.](https://askubuntu.com/questions/377937/how-to-set-a-custom-resolution)

```
$: sudo cvt 1366 768 60
1368x768 59.88 Hz (CVT) hsync: 47.79 kHz; pclk: 85.25 MHz
Modeline "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

$: sudo xrandr --newmode "1368x768_60.00"   85.25  1368 1440 1576 1784  768 771 781 798 -hsync +vsync

$: sudo xrandr --addmode VGA-1 1368x768_60.00
```

Comment: @nightcod3r Answer updated

Comment: @nightcod3r Did this worked?